# How we can connect ELK stack With MSSQL server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am using MSSQL 2014
latest JDK
Latest ELK stack
logstash.conf file
But getting this issue when I make a connection with the SQL server

[image]

```
[main][e9c4db4e3f1cd9e5b60e74315884750f1c29dac2dc7868d0280893eb5f8b6983] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>"Java::ComMicrosoftSqlserverJdbc::SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS13, TLS12]\"
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67246010/the-server-selected-protocol-version-tls10-is-not-accepted-by-client-preferences) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126780/how-to-fix-the-server-selected-protocol-version-tls10-is-not-accepted-by-client) help?

Comment: no i install JDK Firsts means that JRE install automatically in JDK but java.security file does not found

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your connection string:

```
encrypt=true; trustServerCertificate=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

u should enable SSL connection in SQL SERVER

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ok understand then how can I enable SSL for MSSQL

Comment: generate a SSL certificate for SQL SERVER connection

Comment: u will find how u can generate it on google or youtube